# Migration tool between Java and Node.js

Tags: java, node.js, migration

I am wondering whether there are already tools to migrate Node.js code to Java code.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer :**

You won't be able to magically convert your node.js Javascript code to Java.

**However :**

You could have a look at [Nodyn](http://nodyn.io/), which allows you to run Node.js apps on the JVM and helps Node integrating with existing Java apps. I haven't tested it but it seems very serious.

Comment: I cannot use Nodyn at a customer site